# EAS build android app,give error from metro

Tags: android, react-native, expo, metro-bundler, eas

I'm trying to build the application made with **expo** and **react native** where I have extra **android**/**ios** settings, everything works fine until this error appears.

Expo SDK:44.00

React-native:0.64.3

React:17.0.1

```
 Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
 warning: the transform cache was reset.
[stderr] 
● Validation Warning:
[stderr] 
Unknown option "server.experimentalImportBundleSupport" with value false was found.
[stderr] 
 This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.   
[stderr] 
● Validation Warning: 
[stderr] 
Unknown option "server.unstable_serverRoot" with value null was found.
[stderr] 
This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.
[stderr] 
● Validation Warning:
[stderr] 
Unknown option "watcher" with value {"additionalExts": ["cjs", "mjs"], "healthCheck": 
{"enabled": false, "filePrefix": ".metro-health-check", "interval": 30000, "timeout": 
5000}, "unstable_preferTreeFS": false, "watchman": {"deferStates": ["hg.update"]}} was found.
[stderr] 
 This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.
[stderr] 
 ● Validation Warning:
[stderr] 
  Unknown option "unstable_perfLoggerFactory" with value () => {
[stderr] 
  class Logger {
[stderr] 
   start() {}
[stderr] 
  end() {}
[stderr] 
annotate() {}
[stderr] 
 point() {}
[stderr] 
 subSpan() {
[stderr] 
  return this;
 [stderr] 
}
[stderr] 
 }
[stderr] 
 return new Logger();
[stderr] 
  } was found.
[stderr] 
 This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.
--------------------------------------
 > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
                Welcome to Metro!
          Fast - Scalable - Integrated
 [stderr] 
 error index.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match').
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
  at countLines (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native- 
  community/cli/node_modules/metro/src/lib/countLines.js:17:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native- 
community/cli/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:587:24)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native- 
community/cli/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:146:24)
at _next (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native- 
community/cli/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:168:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :react-native-community_checkbox:generateReleaseRFile
[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
[stderr] 
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug 
option 
to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 1m 39s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with 
Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See 
https://docs.gradle.org/6.9
/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
238 actionable tasks: 238 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase 
for more information.
```

And I haven't found anything on the internet.
to solve the problem I tried to configure metro but without success,but until I got stuck.

There is something wrong with @react-native-community.

```
error index.js: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 
'match').
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
at countLines (\node_modules\@react-native- 
community\cli\node_modules\metro\src\lib\countLines.js:17:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (\node_modules\@react-native- 
community\cli\node_modules\metro-transform- 
worker\src\index.js:587:24
```

Comment: I discovered the error, it was from the metro version that was not compatible with the SDK version from the expo.I adapted expo to 45 and metro to version 0.76 and everything is ok.